# Параметр .next() jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеются несколько *div* которые скрыты *display:none*
В *div*-ах есть кнопки *radio* - при клике на которую меняется *div*.

https://codepen.io/zikwal/pen/bGVoZXq  - тут можно посмотреть всё

```js
$('.test-data').find('div:first').show();
$('.test-data').click(()=>{
    const link = $('.pagination a').attr('href');
    const prevActive = $('.pagination > a.nav-active').attr('href');
    $('input[type=radio]').on('change', ()=>{
        $(prevActive).fadeOut(300, ()=>{
            $(link).next().fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Данный код выполняет нужную функцию, но **только 1 раз.** *(То есть - первый div скрывается и открывается 2ой div, но дальше, при клике на radio - никаких изменений не происходит)*

---

**Нужно,** чтобы **и при следующих** нажатиях **на radio** - активный div **скрывался**, а следующий в списке **открывался.**

Comment: `link` и `prevActive` у тебя строки + под `.pagination a` ты имел ввиду `a.pagination` или `>a`

Comment: Дай html код, а то не очень хочется вчитываться во многобуквье

Comment: `<div class="question" data-id="4" id="question-4" style="display: block;">
<p class="q">Вопрос</p>
<p class="a">
<input type="radio" id="answer-1" name="question-4" value="1">
<label for="answer-1">1</label>
</p>
<p class="a">
<input type="radio" id="answer-2" name="question-4" value="2">
<label for="answer-2">2</label>
</p>
</div>`

Вот сам DIV - аналогичные ему стоят в списке с параметрами data-id и id другими.

Comment: @vadim Вставил измененный Вами код - и он выполняет всё то же самое. То есть: один раз выполняет функцию скрытия и открытия следующего div'a при нажатии на radio - а во второй раз игнорирует.

https://codepen.io/zikwal/pen/bGVoZXq 

Вот сам код и как он работает.

Comment: Измененный нами код изменен, был изменен только для визуала, т.е. идентичен но красив

Comment: +в html коде полная разруха, ща сделаю

Comment: используй всякие код_бьютифай или auto_indent плагины для IDE-шек существуют, чтобы не пропускать\допускать [лишний див] и [question 3 вне блока]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ныа

```js
$('.test-data').children('div:first').show();
$('input[id^="answer"]').click(({currentTarget})=>{
    $(currentTarget).parent().parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
    console.log($(currentTarget).attr('name'), $(currentTarget).val());
});
```

```css
.q{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.a {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.question {
    display: none;
}
.nav-active {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<div class="pagination">
    <a class="nav-active" href="#question-6"></a>
    <a class="pre-active" href="#question-4">Next</a>
    <a class="pre-active" href="#question-5">Next</a>
    <a class="pre-active" href="#question-3">Next</a>
    <a class="pre-active" href="#question-2">Next</a>
    <a class="pre-active" href="#question-1">Next</a>
</div>-->

<div class="test-data">
    <div class="question" data-id="6" id="question-6">
        <p class="q">Вопрос 1</p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-1" name="question-6" value="1">
            <label for="answer-1">1</label>
        </p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-2" name="question-6" value="2">
            <label for="answer-2">2</label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="question" data-id="4" id="question-4">
        <p class="q">Вопрос 2</p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-1" name="question-4" value="1">
            <label for="answer-1">1</label>
        </p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-2" name="question-4" value="2">
            <label for="answer-2">2</label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="question" data-id="5" id="question-5">
        <p class="q">Вопрос 3</p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-1" name="question-5" value="1">
            <label for="answer-1">1</label>
        </p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-2" name="question-5" value="2">
            <label for="answer-2">2</label>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```